# OpenCV imshow window cannot be reused when called within a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I'm having trouble using cv2 `imshow` when run in a separate python thread.

The code below works for the first call of `start_cam`, but the second call fails - the cv2 camera window does not reappear. This seems to have something to do with threading prevent that window being reused, because:

If the cv2 window is given a random name then it works indefinitely, although the window is not being reused as each window is new of course.

If `_cam_loop()` is called without threading this it also works and the same window can be reused indefinitely.

```
def start_cam(self):
    self.cam_live = True
    threading.Thread(target = self._cam_loop).start()

def stop_cam(self):
    self.cam_live = False

def _cam_loop(self):
    while self.cam_live:
        img = self.cam.get_image()
        cv2.imshow("cam", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

self.start_cam()   # live image window appears
self.stop_cam()    # image window disappears (as thread is killed)
self.start_cam()   # window fails to reappear
```

The window disappears when the thread finishes. Is there a way to keep a reference to the window after the thread finishes?

Comment: Try cv2.namedWindow("cam"); before using imshow

Comment: Tried in both the main program and the thread, didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: can you try to increase the `cv2.waitKey(1)` to `cv2.waitKey(100)`. And I remember something like cvStartGuiThread which might be necessary to call once from the main thread (C-Api), but not sure about the right name and not sure whether it will help.

Comment: it is `cv2.startWindowThread()`. But not really sure what it's actually good for :D

Comment: Nope, neither worked :(

Comment: This might depend on the back end too -- on the qt back end, imshow or waitKey might block indefinitely if called not from the thread that initially calls it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a way to keep a reference to the named window, but if the window is destroyed it can be reused each time the thread is called. I simply added `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` to the end of the thread function and it worked. Curious to know why exactly.

```
def _cam_loop(self):
    while self.cam_live:
        img = self.cam.get_image()
        cv2.imshow("cam", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```